# One Page Design for Save, Update, Delete, List Functionality

Tags: search, search-results, save, delete

I have a design question: I want to make save, update, delete, show the list of a certain data (for example name). I have done a design that can be in 1 page. But I do not want it to be too complicated.

The other option is to make them in separate pages (maybe tabs (but I do not want tabs either)).

I will conduct user tests, but before that I want to get professional opinion. Can anyone take a look at the design below and make comment?[image]

Comment: What is the relationship between the fields at the top and the table at the bottom?

Comment: they are the same fields, i.e. you save Name field using text input and it is displayed in the table below (like Name 1, Name 2, etc.). Sorry I couldn't change the name of the table in the example.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your fields , if there are any co-relation between this 3 set of fields.

My Recommendation is to go with #tab Structure .It will solve your problem there is no need of going with navigation to another page.

Below Image will give rough idea of how the tab structure is?

[image]